# How to truly Fix this Recent sudden mess up in uBlock Origin (some internal config/ list updates) blocking way too much?

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin

How to truly Fix this Recent sudden mess up in uBlock Origin (some internal config/ list updates) blocking way too much?

Its doing this on most websites: google, youtube, superuser & SE.

Even SE/ SU sites throw up the Javascript not accessible Tab/ Notification upside. Similar to this:

[Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9020/super-user-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-which-is-blocked-or)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the Extension was updated Apr 20, 2020 and all was well, I figured

- It was not the extensions itself
- I had not made any changes within extension config/ settings or in Browser

The only thing that could've changed automatically were some of the Filter Lists within.

So I tried the following after some research and seems to work and fix it.

Ublock Origin > Options > Filter Lists

- Purge All Caches
- Update Now